# Replace Google Analytics with a transparent, privacy-respecting alternative

Tags: feature-request, legal, privacy, cookies, site-analytics

> Earlier this year, Google announced that Universal Analytics (UA) will be going away and will stop processing new data after July 1, 2023.

Stack Exchange [currently plans to switch to Google Analytics 4 (GA4)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/381668/308065). I won't re-iterate the problems with that plan; but why not take this opportunity to use a more suitable alternative, instead?

For price estimates, I'll be assuming 2400 000 000 monthly page views for all of Stack Exchange. Stack Overflow is responsible for most of that. This is *way* more than most companies list on their pricing page, so I've extrapolated; those prices are marked with "conjectured", and are probably overestimates.

### Google Analytics 3 ("Universal Analytics")

- Closed-source JavaScript
- Hosted version ($12 500 per month) blocked by:

  - Firefox Tracking Protection
  - EasyPrivacy
- No self-hosted version
- Doesn't fill in the data gap
- Doesn't respect Do Not Track header

### Google Analytics 4 ("GA4")

- Closed-source JavaScript
- Hosted version ($12 500 per month) blocked by:

  - Firefox Tracking Protection
  - EasyPrivacy
- No self-hosted version
- Attempts to fill in the data gap with <del>magic</del> machine learning, but can't do anything when the browser blocks the script.
- Doesn't respect Do Not Track header

### [Matomo](https://matomo.org/)

- Open-source JavaScript (BSD-3-Clause)
- Hosted version (conjectured €330 000 per month) blocked by:

  - EasyPrivacy ([workaround exists](https://blog.jonlu.ca/posts/matomo-bypass))
- Self-hosted version (libre, GPLv3, PHP-based) blocked by:

  - None known.
- [Can fill in the data gap from server logs.](https://matomo.org/log-analytics/)
- [Respects Do Not Track header by default](https://matomo.org/faq/general/configure-privacy-settings-in-matomo/)

### [GoAccess](https://goaccess.io/)

- No JavaScript
- No hosted version
- Self-hosted version (libre, MIT; C, precompiled binary and Docker versions available) blocked by:

  - Nothing; cannot be blocked
- Has no data gap
- [Can respect Do Not Track header](https://github.com/allinurl/goaccess/issues/1705), depending on server configuration
- No campaign / heatmap support

### [rrweb.io](https://www.rrweb.io/)

- Open-source JavaScript
- No server-side software; you'll need to write your own.
- Blocked by:

  - None known.
- Measures All The Things; a useful tool, but definitely an informed consent opt-in thing, e.g. for reporting usability issues and site bugs. (If enabled for all users all of the time, it'd be a privacy violation, and your servers would buckle under the load.)

### [Fathom](https://usefathom.com/)

- Closed-source JavaScript ([minified, but with variable names preserved](https://cdn.usefathom.com/script.js))
- Hosted version (conjectured $21 920 per month), blocked by:

  - EasyPrivacy ([a workaround exists](https://usefathom.com/features/custom-domains))
- Low data gap
- [Does not respect Do Not Track header by default](https://usefathom.com/docs/script/script-advanced#dnt)
- [GDPR-compliant](https://usefathom.com/features/eu-isolation)

### [Plausible](https://plausible.io/)

- Open-source JavaScript (MIT)
- Hosted version (conjectured $33 800 per month) blocked by:

  - EasyPrivacy ([a workaround exists](https://plausible.io/docs/proxy/introduction), but the EasyPrivacy maintainers don't like it)
- [Self-hosted version](https://plausible.io/self-hosted-web-analytics) (libre, AGPLv3, Docker-based) blocked by:

  - None known.
- Low data gap
- [Does not respect Do Not Track header by default](https://plausible.io/docs/integration-guides#dnt-and-offline-functionality)

### [Simple Analytics](https://www.simpleanalytics.com/)

- [Open-source JavaScript](https://github.com/simpleanalytics/scripts) (MIT)
- Hosted version (conjectured £141 120) blocked by:

  - EasyPrivacy
- No self-hosted version
- Low data gap (with `<noscript>` fallback)
- [Respects Do Not Track header by default](https://docs.simpleanalytics.com/dnt)

### [GoatCounter](https://www.goatcounter.com/)

- Open-source JavaScript (ISC)
- No known commercial self-hosted version, but you could ask.
- Self-hosted version (libre, modified EUPL, PostgreSQL/SQLite and Go-based) blocked by:

  - None known
- Near-zero data gap
- [Ignores Do Not Track header](https://www.arp242.net/dnt.html)

### [Piwik PRO](https://piwik.pro/) (proprietary Matomo fork)

- Closed-source(?) JavaScript
- Hosted version (unknown price) blocked by:

  - EasyPrivacy
- On-premises version (unknown price) blocked by:

  - Unknown
- Unknown data gap (with `<noscript>` fallback)

### [Cloudflare Analytics](https://www.cloudflare.com/analytics/)

- It's Cloudflare. You don't use Cloudflare.
- It's only here for completeness; I have no idea how their pricing works.
- No data gap, by technicality.

Comment: I'm certain I've missed some options. That's what comments are for! TODO: analyse Stack Exchange's requirements, and see which of these is the best for them.

Comment: [Matomo's glossary](https://glossary.matomo.org/) is going to be helpful.

Comment: What is *"MIT; C"*? [MIT License](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIT_License) for C source code?

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum Yes. The software is MIT-licensed, and it's written in C.

Comment: hm, One potential sticking point is while SE's fairly cool about adblockers - they get a fair amount of revenue off  ads and they use google to serve them. Whatever alternative may need to work with that, assuming its a factor

Comment: @JourneymanGeek While Google Analytics _does_ contain Google Ads-related code, afaict linking Google Analytics and Google Ads is to measure the effectiveness of ads that Stack Exchange pays for on _other_ sites. I don't see that it affects how much money you get from ads on _your_ site.

Comment: I've found a whole bunch more alternatives listed on [tinyanalytics.io](https://tinyanalytics.io/google-analytics-alternatives); some of them are no good, but many seem okay. I don't currently have the capacity to add them to the list in the question.

Comment: I definitely agree: Google Analytics is terrible for user privacy, and it contributes to Google's huge Internet monopoly. Using a more privacy-respecting analytics service run by a smaller organization is for sure the way to go.

Comment: Funny that it's somewhat related to your name @wizzwizz4, but I built [UXWizz](https://www.uxwizz.com) over the past 13 years, it's not as popular as the other solutions, but simpler to install, more performant and a lot cheaper for the self-hosted version. You might need some technical knowledge to be able to scale a plain MySQL database to hundreds of millions of pageviews per month though...

Comment: @Cristy UXWizz looks pretty good to me! I'm not sure that it does everything Stack Exchange requires – I can't see how to do conversion funnel analysis –, but I'm not sure _what_ Stack Exchange requires, so it might do all they need.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Thanks! Actual funnels will be implemented soon (now I'm releasing ChatGPT integration to have text-to-mysql interactions). Currently, you can do funnels by creating different segments (e.g. [ALL], [visited /pricing], [visited /pricing + complete checkout]) and comparing their numbers.

UXWizz might be a better fit to small to medium websites though, than to huge websites like Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 24):

## What functionality does Stack Exchange need?

### 25k analytics

Analytics accessible to users. Aside from stats that come directly from the database (posts and votes), there's:

#### Page views

This is the total number of page loads, counting the same user multiple times. All analytics systems can do this, though systems that can use server logs (GoAccess, Matomo, Plausible, GoatCounter) are the most complete. (Cloudflare comes in at a close second, but it has trouble filtering out scrapers and spiders.)

#### Visits

This is the number of distinct users who visit the site. Supported by:

- [Matomo](https://matomo.org/faq/general/faq_43/)
- [Fathom](https://usefathom.com/api)
- [Plausible](https://plausible.io/plausible.io)
- [Simple Analytics](https://docs.simpleanalytics.com/metrics)
- [GoatCounter](https://github.com/arp242/goatcounter/blob/master/docs/sessions.markdown#user-content-goatcounters-solution)

#### New visits

Visits from users who are not known to have visited before.

- [Matomo](https://matomo.org/faq/general/faq_21418/)

#### Traffic sources (% direct, referring, search)

- [Matomo](https://demo.matomo.cloud/)
- Fathom
- [Plausible](https://plausible.io/plausible.io/sources)
- [Simple Analytics](https://simpleanalytics.com/simpleanalytics.com?from=landing)
- [GoatCounter](https://static.zgo.at/screenshot2.png)

##### Referring sites

- [Matomo](https://demo.matomo.cloud/)
- Fathom
- Plausible
- [Simple Analytics](https://docs.simpleanalytics.com/metrics)
- GoatCounter

##### Search queries

I'm not confident Google Analytics' search queries data [is at *all* accurate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/152348/308065). But maybe it's better for bigger sites.

- [Matomo](https://matomo.org/guide/installation-maintenance/import-search-keywords/)
- [Plausible](https://plausible.io/docs/google-search-console-integration)

### Campaigns

I've seen Stack Exchange use UTM query strings.

- [Matomo](https://matomo.org/subcategory/campaigns/)
- [Fathom](https://usefathom.com/docs/features/campaigns)
- [Plausible](https://plausible.io/plausible.io/utm_campaigns)
- [Simple Analytics](https://docs.simpleanalytics.com/strict-utms)

### A/B testing

Stack Exchange uses Google Analytics for A/B testing. I'm going to try to piece this together from what Stackers have posted publicly, but if anyone at Stack Exchange could fill me in on which features you use, that'd be really helpful! (Do you use "conversions" features?)

### Google Analytics import

GA4 does *not* support importing data from GA3 ("Universal Analytics"). These do:

- [Matomo](https://matomo.org/faq/how-to/faq_102/)
- [Fathom](https://usefathom.com/blog/google-analytics-importer)
- [Plausible](https://plausible.io/docs/google-analytics-import)
- [Simple Analytics](https://docs.simpleanalytics.com/import-google-analytics-data)

### Google Ads

To my knowledge, Google Analytics does not affect the amount of money you get from Google Ads. ([Nor does it arbitrarily affect Google search rankings](https://nitter.net/JohnMu/status/1012320567381422081), though a lighter alternative would obviously be better for SEO.) All alternatives would be equivalent, in this respect.

### The data gap

Many people refuse consent, opt-out of, or block analytics systems. Google Analytics is perhaps the most blocked system, but many others are blocked by the EasyPrivacy list used by many ad-blockers.

If this data gap was *uniform*, you could fill it in by extrapolating. However, it's not; certain demographics are disproportionately represented in this blocking, [as Marko Saric reports](https://markosaric.com/google-analytics-blocking/):

> Considering the fact that Plausible Analytics and Google Analytics measure unique visitors in a different way, I also looked at the total page views:
>
> |  | Plausible | Google | Difference |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | Tech site | 16,853 | 11,626 | 31% |
> | Lifestyle site | 9,520 | 9,375 | 2% |
> | Foodie site | 15,811 | 14,492 | 9% |
> | Total | 42,184 | 35,493 | 16% |

Marko Saric also found differences between OS, browser and device.

We have different levels of not-consenting on different Stack Exchange sites, too. From most, to least, affected by the [10th of May analytics drop](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/378440/308065):

| name | page views | visits | new visits |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| lifehacks | 0.0636 | 0.0501 | 0.0322 |
| spanish | 0.0687 | 0.0461 | 0.0250 |
| ell | 0.1323 | 0.1098 | 0.0501 |
| boardgames | 0.1359 | 0.1035 | 0.0569 |
| apple | 0.2129 | 0.1875 | 0.0996 |
| chess | 0.3780 | 0.2580 | 0.0947 |
| stackapps | 0.3978 | 0.2343 | 0.1621 |
| puzzling | 0.4450 | 0.2227 | 0.0755 |
| retrocomputing | 0.4456 | 0.3235 | 0.1068 |
| meta | 0.5080 | 0.3963 | 0.2326 |

Naïvely comparing this year's data up to 2022-05-09, versus 2022-05-10 to present: Lifehacks lost 94% of its page view data, but Meta Stack Exchange "only" lost 49%. Think of the demographics of these sites; is this impacting your use of analytics?

Google's got two data gaps to work with, here:

- Users who don't consent to GA. Google can try to fill this in with machine learning, but it only has the data from "consenting" users to work with. Machine learning can extrapolate, but it's not magic; it doesn't work if it doesn't have good data.
- Users who *block* Google Analytics entirely. As far as I'm aware, GA4 doesn't *attempt* to fill this data in.

Google Analytics 4's "Consent Mode" might give you the confidence that you can see the bigger picture, but I don't see how it's *possible* for their system to do this, given how they've described it working. Google Analytics has *two* blind spots, and "Consent Mode" claims it can fill *one* of those in with machine learning.

You know what *has* access to every single page view on your site? The Stack Exchange servers. [Urchin, the original Google Analytics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urchin_(software)), worked by analysing server logs, but modern Google Analytics doesn't support this feature.

- GoAccess does; in fact, that's all it does. (Same with [AWStats](https://www.awstats.org/).)
- Matomo [accepts server logs as an additional data source](https://matomo.org/guide/tracking-data/import-server-logs/).
- Plausible [allows server log imports](https://github.com/plausible/analytics/discussions/211), and an [endpoint for server-side analytics](https://plausible.io/docs/events-api).
- Simple Analytics has a [dedicated endpoint for server-side analytics](https://docs.simpleanalytics.com/server-side-tracking).

#### Uptime collection feature

Needs research. [Mentioned in this comment](/questions/381904/the-flow-state-homepage-is-tracking-users-without-consent#comment1273827_381912).

Comment: Btw, if you have 25k on any sites _not_ on this list, I'd appreciate some more entries for my table. You can help by visiting `/site-analytics` on your site, changing the From box to "2022-Jan-01", and exporting the Traffic CSV.

Comment: A small note on search queries: Plausible can be connected to the Google Search console to pull in search query data for analytics: https://plausible.io/docs/google-search-console-integration

Comment: @MatthewSchlachter Fixed.